# What does Spitze mean specifically in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I was reading a famous news site online and came across this

> Neue schwere Vorwürfe gegen FIFA-Spitze

Spitze has many translations. Based on context I assume it to be "top" which makes me wonder...  does the term imply one (the very top) or several persons?

Comment: Do they? I feel that one meaning of one of the words fits the context perfectly.

Comment: @jan I guess is top, right?

Comment: Top or peak, yes.

Comment: @Jan should i delete the question?

Comment: We can just close it; it’ll get deleted eventually. Unless you really want to delete it immediately ;)

Comment: With *FIFA's top people* you have indeed guessed a good translation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When refering to `Spitze` of an organisation, it's not clear whether it's one person or a group of persons but in all cases, it's the person/group who/which is leading the organisation, the top or head of it.

Comment: True about the ambiguity in principle, although in a concrete situation it's almost always several people because if it's only one it's much more more common to say *Chef* or use the specific word for the person's role (typially *Präsident* or *Vorsitzender*).

Answer (score 4):

*FIFA-Spitze* could be translated as *FIFA leadership*.

Answer (score 1):

Spitze ist hier eine Metapher, also ein bildhafter Ersatzausdruck, für den Präsidenten, also Fifa-Präsident Blatter. Vergleich mit einem Berg. Blatter ist die Spitze der Organisation.

Answer (score 0):

The same like the english FiFA-Top, Spitze = Top